# Server or Local version when merging?

Tags: c#, tfs, merge

I started merging 2 branches, resolved all conflicts, now i have a lot of files to check-in. I started to look through all these files and the 1st file shows me this when i click compare to latest version:

[image: image of files]

I see that there is no changes were made but this file wants to check-in, what to do? I think I need to exclude this file from checking-in (with operation "undo") to keep commit clear. Am I right? Is it normal for operation "merge"? Or I have to commit everything? And why this file is in "check-in" section?

Comment: It could be a whitespace change, or a file encoding change, or just TFS being TFS. Personally I would undo the change, but there aren't any hard and fast rules about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just undo the change.

There is clearly no functional issue, just a formatting/encoding issue between your codebase and the one you are merging from. Often I see similar when different users select different line ending preferences in their local git configuration. There may be other options that could result in similar behaviour.

[See the GitHub article on line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)